# Convert user local time to gmt unix timestamp in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

If you load codeigniter's date helper, there will be the function "local_to_gmt()" but it takes no argument and only converts current server time (that is generated by time() ).

I need the function to be able to convert any other time given from user according to his local time and DST fields in database.

Or a function like human_to_unix() with 2 more parameters: dst and local time.

Does such a function exist?

---

I had said: local_to_gmt() takes no argument, but as the first answerer says it DOES take an argument as well.
**But I'm focusing on user timezone and daylight saving options.**

---

THE 3RD UPDATE!!!

I have found a solution but according to stackoverlow's laws I couldn't answer my own question until some hours later.

Look at this function that might be the nearest solution for me until now: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/convert_to_gmt

```
function convert_to_gmt($time = '', $timezone = 'UTC', $dst = FALSE)
{            
    if ($time == '')
    {
        return now();
    }

    $time -= timezones($timezone) * 3600;

    if ($dst == TRUE)
    {
       $time -= 3600;
    }

    return $time;
}
```

But there is still a question:

Do you believe that the $dst will work without any problem? As I understand, according to the function the $dst will ALWAYS decrease one hour. But it should be realized weather it is summer or not. It will decrease the time even if it's winter!!!

How to overcome this problem???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php) - Also please see the many related questions on the right and use the site search.

Comment: There is no relation between my question and the link you commented. I'm talking about user specific timezone and DST setting. But none of the question and the best answer (I only read those 2) were about user local time; thnx anyway

Comment: It's not clever to ask for a function that does what you need but better to look how it's done. The duplicate was not really fitting I must confess, but I also pointed you to other related questions on the right, e.g. (just picking *one* of the many) [PHP, Codeigniter: How to Set Date/Time based on users timezone/location globally in a web app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274568/php-codeigniter-how-to-set-date-time-based-on-users-timezone-location-globally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `gm` group functions in PHP like:

- [gmmktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmmktime.php)

When I asked the question, I didn't know that PHP has those functions, so I'd looked up such a behavior in Codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

[Manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html) says:

> **local_to_gmt()**
> Takes a Unix timestamp as input and returns it as GMT

... and provides this example:

```
$now = time();
$gmt = local_to_gmt($now);
```

So I'd dare say that it actually accepts an argument.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right. But it doesn't care about user local time and DST settings.

Comment: Unix timestamps are "universal", they don't contain time zone information because they are the same no matter where you are. You take time zone into account when you convert from/to regular dates (e.g. 19/01/2012 13:14).

Comment: Yes, you are right. And because of that I want a function to affect the time user gives (according to his database fields in user table) and then convert it to unix timestamp. This way, I will be able to have my own calculations on it, and I'll also be able to show the time in other users' local times.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not a CI user. I had expected that is was a simple case of manual misread. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: Dear friend, I really appreciate your tries. Thank you very much for your comments :)